# How to store objects with different types in a vector

Tags: c++

I have three classes that inherit from the class component.
In class Computer I want to store objects of these 3 classes in a vector.

```
class Component {
public:
    double price;
    virtual void show() {
        std::cout << "Price: " << this->price << std::endl;
    }
};

class CPU : public Component {
public:
    double price;
    CPU(double price){ this->price = price; }
    void show() {
        std::cout << "CPU Price: " << this->price << std::endl;
    }
};

class RAM : public Component {
public:
    double price;
    RAM(double price){ this->price = price; }
    void show() {
        std::cout << "RAM Price: " << this->price << std::endl;
    }
};

class SSD : public Component {
public:
    double price;
    SSD(double price){ this->price = price; }
    virtual void show() {
        std::cout << "RAM Price: " << this->price << std::endl;
    }
};

class Computer : public Component {
public:
    std::vector<Component*> vec;
    void show() {
        for (auto el: vec) {
            std::cout << el->price << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

But when I try to do it I see the garbage there:

```
Computer c;
c.vec.push_back((Component*)new RAM(10));
c.show(); // garbage
std::cout << c.vec[0]->price << std::endl; // garbage
```

I read a few questions about this on the stackoverflow, but still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your base class `Component` should have a virtual destructor.  If not, calling `delete` on those pointers inside of your vector will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring a `double price;` in each subclass. This creates *separate* fields, i.e. `RAM::price` and `SSD::price`, in addition to `Component::price`. Thus, when you construct a `new RAM(10)`, it only assigns `10` to `RAM::price`, and not `Component::price`. That's why you're getting garbage.

To fix, simply remove all those extra declarations.

Also, to aid with properly deleting those pointers you've created, I'd highly suggest using a vector of smart pointers (probably `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>`). Then you could just:

```
c.vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Component>(new RAM(10)));
```

and use it as normal; the pointers will get `delete`d when the vector is destructed.